# jQuery tabs mouseover and mouseleave

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery UI tabs plugin. It functions well on mouse hover, but on mouse leave the tabs' content still appears. Here is the code:

```
<script>    
    $(function() {          
        $( "#tabs").tabs({ event: "mouseover",active: false,collapsible: true,});
    }); 
</script>
```

Is there any option how  to collapse the tab content on mouse leave?

Comment: How you can do it with formating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mrdeveloper: finally it does. I have forgotten to put the jquery functions inside the main function:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
    <link href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="1.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {

        $("#text1,#text2,#text3").hide();
$("#1,#2,#3").mouseleave(function()
            { 
$("#text1,#text2,#text3").hide();
            });
$("#1").mouseenter(function()
            { 
                $("#text1").show();
                 $("#text2,#text3").hide();
            });
$("#2").mouseenter(function()
            { 
                $("#text2").show();
                 $("#text1,#text3").hide();
            });
$("#3").mouseenter(function()
            { 
                $("#text3").show();
                 $("#text2,#text1").hide();
            });



    });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="tab">
    <span id="1">Tab 1</span>    
    <span id="2">Tab 2</span>   
    <span id="3">Tab 3</span>   
</div>
<div class="text" id="text1"><b>Text 1:</b>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. </div>
<div class="text" id="text2"><b>Text 2: </b> Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. </div>
<div class="text" id="text3"><b>Text 3:</b> Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu.</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot mrdeveloper. Hope I will have correct answers for you. Have i nice day*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
event: "mouseover"
});
```

See below link

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#mouseover

Comment: This answer adds just the event mouse over. My questions is for collapsible content tabs.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hsakapandit/z4HYu/4/

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({event:'mouseleave',collapsible: true,active:false});
```

**Updated:** Same effect with JQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/hsakapandit/z4HYu/11/

Comment: You meant , you want to hide all div content when you dont hover on any tab

Comment: Yes. Do you have any idea how to do that and improve our knowledge about jQuery?

Comment: Why dont you just use JQuery methods instead Jquery UI tabs() method to achieve what u want. Jquery UI has been derived from JQuery only. So If you are not finding your solution using JQuery UI , make a solution by using JQuery.

Comment: OK, and how can you do that with jQuery?

Comment: Check this fiddle: Hope this ll help you http://jsfiddle.net/hsakapandit/z4HYu/11/

Comment: Add code like this-> $(document).ready(function(){ `code here`  }) Also HTML and CSS for this fiddle is different. Updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hsakapandit/z4HYu/12/

Comment: Thank you. What if we add an unordered list and make a drop down jquery menu, how we can do it? For now it functions well but when I what to touch the div content it disappears? Thank you, have a nice day

Comment: I think you should ask new question regarding your next problem.